# The structure of the GCC library?

Tags: compiler-construction

What is the structure of GCC's source-code?  Is it modular?

What is the fastest way to reference particular items defined in C/CPP compilers?  For example, how do programmers independently track down the class definitions of operators or the order of precedence of operators?

Comment: Judge for yourself -- https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc -- is it modular?

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thank you.  I've already taken to the idea of reading the source code in its entirety as soon as possible, but when you pick up a book the first thing you jump to is usually the index.  I thought someone might know of a reference or a map that gives an overview of various ways of dissecting a compiler.  Maybe it would help to decide the order in which to read the files.

Comment: There's a manual called GCC internals; you'll find it on the GCC documentation page. It would be a good place to start, I think. There you will find documentation of how operators are turned into machine code, which I guess is what you're asking about.

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e9/GNU_C_Compiler_Internals.pdf This is a link to that book, I think.

Comment: That's an old version of the book. You probably want the current version, on the gcc website: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/ There's lots of other useful information on https://gcc.gnu.org/; that should be your first point of call if you are interested in GCC development.